# How to use ngx-infinite-scroll in mat-autocomplete

Tags: angular, typescript, mat-autocomplete, ngx-infinite-scroll

I want to use [ngx-infinite-scroll](https://github.com/orizens/ngx-infinite-scroll) in mat-autocomplete but seems that it does not triggered `scrolled` event when scroll bar reach to the end of mat autocomplete panel.

What I tried: [complete code is Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-autocomplete-lb4frd?file=app%2Fautocomplete-display-example.html,main.ts,app%2Fautocomplete-display-example.ts,app%2Fautocomplete-display-example.css)

```
<input type="text"
       matInput
       [matAutocomplete]="auto1"/>
  <mat-autocomplete
    #auto1="matAutocomplete"
    [class]="'blue-bg'"
    infiniteScroll
    [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"
    [infiniteScrollUpDistance]="15"
    (scrolled)="onScroll()">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of simpleOptions.slice(0, 30)"
      [value]="option">
      {{ option }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
```

and in the component class I have:

```
  onScroll() {
    console.log('load more data');
  }
```

My expectation is when the scroll bar reached to the end of the panel, `onScroll` methods would be called.